# How to skip enlisting a certain child module from a parent's maven site

Tags: maven-site-plugin

Suppose, I have a parent pom with following modules:

moduleA
moduleB
moduleC

Note: I have not created a site.xml for the parent project

When I do a mvn clean site:attach-descriptor site site:stage on the parent project, the index.html file generated in the parent-project-folder/target/staging, displays a modules section enlisting all the modules(moduleA,moduleB and moduleC) that link to their respective staged site content. But I have skipped site generation for moduleB and hence site folder for moduleB is not generated. Is there a way by which I can exclude moduleB from being enlisted in the modules section of the parent project's maven site? Because, if it is present, the link refers to a page not found as there is no site content for this module.